# Flex masonry effect not wrapping properly

Tags: css, flexbox

I have the following layout that I'm trying to achieve with flex, but just can't seem to get it:

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.box {
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: 50%;
  padding-top: 25%;
  float: left;
}

.box:first-child {
  padding-top: 50%;
}

.box:nth-last-child(-n+2) {
  width: 25%;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
</div>
```

If I try to use flex-direction row, it wraps the last two boxes under the first left box

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.box {
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: 50%;
  padding-top: 25%;
}

.box:first-child {
  padding-top: 50%;
}

.box:nth-last-child(-n+2) {
  width: 25%;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
</div>
```

If I use flex direction column, I get closer but have to set a height which means I lose responsiveness

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  height:400px;
  width:100%;
}

.box {
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: 50%;
  padding-top: 25%;
}

.box:first-child {
  padding-top: 50%;
}

.box:nth-last-child(-n+2) {
  width: 25%;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
</div>
```

Is there a way to achieve this layout using flex without having a fixed height or changing the html structure?

Comment: Not if the four boxes are all children of the same parent, I think you would need to introduce at least another grouping element … The problem here is that you are not working in one dimension only, you do not have rows _or_ cols, you have both - and that means this would be rather a job for CSS grid to begin with.

Comment: hmmm, I thought as much.  Was thinking of using grid, might just be the push I needed to move onto it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using flexbox you can consider some *hack* to approximate this. One trick is to have two rows (keep the row direction) and use negative margin on the first element to make it overlap the second row:

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.box {
  outline: 1px solid black;
  width: 50%;
  padding-top: 25%;
}

.box:first-child {
  padding-top: 25%;
  margin-bottom:-25%;
}

.box:nth-last-child(-n+2) {
  width: 25%;
}
.box:nth-child(3) {
  margin-left:auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
</div>
```