# How do I make it so that flex elements occupy these spaces?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have a simple structure like so...

```
<li>1</li> 
<li>2</li> 
<li>3</li> 
<li>4</li> 
<li>5</li>
```

I styled it so that the first box has twice the area of the rest. When I try to flex the elements, box 4 and 5 goes under box 1 instead of box 2 and 3. Here's an image of [what I want](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jQIZj.png) and [what happens](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mp9PG.png). Hopefully I explained it well enough.

here's a quick jsfiddle - https://jsfiddle.net/9h7mjenq/4/

Sorry if this is something basic that I should know, I did try searching for it, but my googling isnt on point lately.

Comment: basically flexbox is not meant to be create such layout when having a row direction

Comment: a similar situation in case you want to use flexbox for this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54632770/8620333

Comment: @TemaniAfif I guess I'll just have to do it in column direction. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can layout those elements in a *similar* way with flexbox, but the ordering would be slightly different. The trick is to use flex-direction: column and clamp the height of the container, so to wrap folowing li items in new columns.

Here is your fiddle slightly modified:

```css
body {
  background: #000;
}

#container {
  width: 500px;
  height: 250px;
  background: #fff;
  flex-flow: column wrap;
  display: flex;
}

li {
  width: 115px;
  height: 115px;
  margin: 5px;
  background: #0000ff;
}

li:nth-of-type(1) {
  width: 235px;
  height: 235px;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <li>1</li>
  <li>2</li>
  <li>3</li>
  <li>4</li>
  <li>5</li>
</div>
```

Comment: I guess I'll have to do it this way. Thanks!